# PreparedStatement equivalent to JDBCTemplate.update(String, Object[])?

Tags: prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

So I have been [lead to believe](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys) that this is the most efficient way of getting an auto-generated ID value from a database using a JDBCTemplate:

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps =
                connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {"ID_FIELD"});
            // Configure the PreparedStatement HERE!
            return ps;
        }
    },
    keyHolder);
```

My problem is that I'm often inserting a variable number of values (`JDBCTemplate.update(String, Object[])` is actually exactly what I need), and it looks like `PreparedStatement` allows insertion of one at a time (`setString` and the like). Looping through the array seems to be so... inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since this is a tumbleweed, I'm guessing that there are no other ways to accomplish this. I ended up creating a class to handle this so that I can get around the requirement for *final*.